# Removing spurious taxa from a phyloseq object - take 2

Tags: phyloseq

Someone gave me a PERFECT set of code for a code I asked a few weeks ago:
Goal: remove taxa that do not make up at least 0.25% of reads in at least one sample (from Reitmeier et al. 2021).

Unfortunately, Stack Overflow's bot decided to delete the question, so I can't find whoever answered this. The code worked great for getting rid of spurious taxa, but now I have another question. I need to look at number of reads per sample, but using readcount() is giving me a proportion instead of an integer. I was hoping someone might be able to work through this. Original code below.

```r
require("phyloseq")

# Load example data
data("GlobalPatterns")
ps <- GlobalPatterns


# Convert counts to proportions
ps_prop <- transform_sample_counts(physeq = ps, 
                                   fun = function(x){x/sum(x)})

# Keep only taxa with at least 0.25% abundance in at least one sample
keep <- filter_taxa(ps_prop, 
            function(x){max(x) > 0.0025})

# Filter out all other taxa
ps_filtered <- prune_taxa(taxa = keep,
                          x = ps)
ps_prop_filtered <- prune_taxa(taxa = keep,
                               x = ps_prop)
```

Comment: Are you calling `sample_sums()` on `ps_filtered` or on `ps_prop_filtered`? Calling it on `ps_filtered` should yield read counts.

Comment: Yeah, using ps_filtered still returns decimals.

Comment: I just checked it with your GlobalPatterns example, and `sample_sums(ps_filtered)` yields integer read counts.

Answer (score 0):

Call `phyloseq::sample_sums()` on `ps_filtered` to obtain summed read counts per sample.

```r
require("phyloseq")

data("GlobalPatterns")
ps <- GlobalPatterns


# Convert counts to proportions
ps_prop <- transform_sample_counts(physeq = ps, fun = function(x){x/sum(x)})

# Keep only taxa with at least 0.25% abundance in at least one sample
keep <- filter_taxa(ps_prop, function(x){max(x) > 0.0025})

# Filter out all other taxa
ps_filtered <- prune_taxa(taxa = keep, x = ps)

# Get library size after filtering
sample_sums(ps_filtered)
#>      CL3      CC1      SV1  M31Fcsw  M11Fcsw  M31Plmr  M11Plmr  F21Plmr 
#>   400514   453761   309333  1407544  1947909   629289   333770   152621 
#>  M31Tong  M11Tong LMEpi24M SLEpi20M   AQC1cm   AQC4cm   AQC7cm      NP2 
#>  1950503    94030  1939076  1107526   927407  1837203  1204698   480069 
#>      NP3      NP5  TRRsed1  TRRsed2  TRRsed3     TS28     TS29    Even1 
#>  1315852  1484502    38018   378431   206191   862775  1128209  1165701 
#>    Even2    Even3 
#>   933843  1038002
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>